# Some tips to help with homesickness

Tags: infinitives

1. *Some tips **to help with homesickness.***

Q1) Is the clause in bold a *relative-infinitival*? (*some tips **that can** help with homesickness*)

Q2) Can I replace the *to-infinitive* with *for+ving*? (*Some tips **for helping** with homesickness*)

Comment: **Q1**: I would call it a "Relative infinitive clause". **Q2** Not without some ambiguity. If you omit the "for" it becomes clearer.

Comment: In informal contexts, yes, but as Greybeard says, ambiguity arises (as it often does when opting for an ing-clause). Here, I'd say the default reading of 'Some tips for helping with homesickness' is 'Some tips about how to help the homesick'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, *Here, I'd say the default reading of 'Some tips for helping with homesickness' is 'Some tips **about how to help** the homesick'.*----I think "for+Ving" is used in the same way in "some tips for learning English easily" = *some tips **about how to learn** English easily*. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but note that _teaching_ involves others, _learning_ is reflexive (in the non-linguistic sense).